# Change Margin Top iText PDFdinamically

Tags: java, html, itext

I've made a solution (JAVA and iText) to generate a PDF from an html rendering treatments for header and footer.

I am using iText 5.5.9 and java 1.7.

The user will be able to choose if the header should repeat on the every page, this it happens when the user
chooses an html template that has a tag that says it can or can not repeat the header

The problem I'm having is regarding the top margin of the content that goes on the page.

There will always be the header on the first page, so I create the document with the top margin with the value that I need:

```
 document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 85.35826771653F, 56.90551181102F, 140, 130.90551181102F);
```

- Situation 1 (it is ok)

When the html has page breaks I can change the top to the text to go up a bit more :

```
for (Element e : this.pdfProcessor.parseToElementList(pageHTML, null)) {
   document.add(e);

   if (pageline == 0 && this.modeloTemplateMPF) {
      if (this.headerNoLoop) {
          document.setMargins(85.35826771653F, 56.90551181102F, 60F, 130.90551181102F);
       } else {
          document.setMargins(85.35826771653F, 56.90551181102F, 140F, 130.90551181102F);
    }
  }
}
```

The method parseToElementList:

```
public ElementList parseToElementList(String html, String css) throws Exception {
    ElementList elements = null;

    try {
        // CSS
        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        if (css != null) {
            CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new ByteArrayInputStream(css.getBytes()));
            cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);
        }

        // HTML
        CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(FontFactory.getFontImp());
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
        htmlContext.setImageProvider(this.base64ImageProvider);

        // Pipelines
        elements = new ElementList();
        ElementHandlerPipeline end = new ElementHandlerPipeline(elements, null);
        HtmlPipeline htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, end);
        CssResolverPipeline cssPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);

        // XML Worker
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(cssPipeline, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

    return elements;
}
```

- Situation 2 (it is ok)

If I have the header on every page I will have no problem.

- Situation 3 (it is NOT ok)

But when the html does not come with page breaks, iText itself does the page break but then the TOP margin always stays the same as it was defined when creating the document. In this case with the value 140.

How do I have iText consider change the top margin from the second page in this case of an html without page break?

Comment: As soon as you call `document.open()`, the first page including its margins is initialized. If you then call `setMargins`, the new margins count for the next pages, not the first.

Comment: I did this. I call setMargins, but there is no difference on the result.